# Sample script for calling a stored procedure with loadrunner?

Tags: stored-procedures, loadrunner

Im very new to loadrunner. I couldnt find any online material on running stored procs (for mssql) for loadrunner script. it says it need to be ansi c. I even wrote a c# that connects to db and call the stored proc in question and then used it for "recording" the task. after running it, it didnt generate the script i was hoping for. is that how it suppose to work? i doubt it :P help. pls point me to a good site or sample script pls. Thanks!

Comment: Please destroy the answer by a critical comment, or accept it. But don't let us hanging in the dark. If you found a solution, post an answer your own question, you can accept it one day later.

Comment: Ah -- does the greyed-out "steve" handle mean that the account is gone meanwhile? What happens with such unanswered questions that the poster has shamefully abandoned by quitting SO altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `lrd_*` functions for ODBC. In this case you'll need `lrd_stmt` to write your SQL statement followed by `lrd_exec` to execute it.

I can't give an example as I don't have an application to record to hand, but the function reference should give you the information you need.

Comment: +1 for that, if lrd_* includes lr_ora8*. However be prepared a) to dig into the oracle interface documentation (available online), and b) to reverse-engineer the kind of code that VUgen records for Oracle calls, for example for a simple query. That will give you a taste of the complexity in the interface, and that is not exactly low. And more important, you will not have to start from scratch if you start with a short recorded script. Might take one evening or two, but very well accomplishable. Sorry I do not have an example at hand, just record Oracle calls and try to understand them.